# How many ways can numbers be split into different groups

Tags: combinatorics

If I had the numbers [2,2,2,2,3,3] and I wanted to find the number of ways to split them into two groups, then how would I do it.

I know that if I had all different numbers eg.[1,2,3,4,5,6] then I would have three ways of making groups, having groups of size [1 and 5] then [2 and 4] then [3 and 3]. Therefore, to find all the ways of splitting them into groups, I would simply do $${6 \choose 1} + {6 \choose 2} + {6 \choose 3}=6+15+20=41$$
However, how can I do it with numbers like those specified at the start, where I have repeats.

The overall question is like this:
I have a list of numbers, several of which are repeats. I want to find the number of ways in which I can split them into  x groups so that the product of the groups in each case is different eg. for my initial example the groups [2,3,3][2,2,2] and [3,3,2][2,2,2] are the same-I want combinations not permutations. Also, by needing different products each time, there are some cases which I have to remove.

I want to know if there is a formula of the number of ways in which a list of numbers(containing repeats) can be split into x groups, of any size>1, such that the products of each group in the set of groups is different. the example is of course [2,2,2,2,3,3] and the answers would be:

[2] and [2,2,2,3,3]

[3] and [2,2,2,2,3]

[2,2] and [2,2,3,3]

[2,3] and [2,2,2,3]

[3,3] and [2,2,2,2]

[2,2,2] and [2,3,3]

[2,2,3] and [2,2,3] (However this can be discounted because products are 12 and 12)

This leaves 6 answers.

If you find any of this question unclear, comment and I will clarify it for you.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your $6 \choose 3$ for the example of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ double counts because you get $\{1,2,3\}$ for the first set and separately $\{4,5,6\}$.  There are actually $31$ divisions.  Another way to see it is to put $1$ on the left, then each other number has two choices where to be, but you exclude the one case where all the numbers are on the left.  $2^5-1=31$

Comment: With the product restriction, this is unlikely to be the sort of thing that has a nice closed formula. However, if you want to start with a count of just how many ways to split into two groups (with possibly the same product), we can get a simple formula for that.

Comment: As Ross points out, your calculation in the case of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ was incorrect. It is also more natural to allow one of the groups to be empty (the count will be just a bit nicer, and that's just good combinatorial sense.)

Comment: Thanks, I do now see that my 6C3 was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the product restriction for now, you can consider the ways to split each number separately.  With four twos, you have five choices for how many are on the left.  With two threes, you have tree choices for how many are on the left.  This gives $5 \cdot 3=15$ choices, but we subtract two because all the numbers on the same side is not allowed.  We have counted each division twice except for those which have exactly half the numbers on each side.  That is possible here.  It is exactly the case where the products will be equal.  We delete that case and divide by two to get the six cases you found.  If you have $a_1$ of the first number, $a_2$ of the second, etc. there will be $$\frac 12\left(\prod (a_i+1)[-1]\right)-1$$ where the $[-1]$ applies if all the $a_i$ are even and the last $-1$ removes the case where one group is even.

This will be fine as long as there is no way to make a case with matching products unless we split the numbers evenly, such as the numbers being distinct primes.  If your list were $[2,2,2,2,4,4]$ we would have other combinations to exclude and you would just have to compute.

Comment: Thanks or your answer, but I am just wondering if there is some way of making the formula more general, for example if I wanted to split the numbers into 3 groups

Comment: The naive approach is not much harder.  Given $a$ items there are ${a+1 \choose 2}=\frac 12(a+1)a$ ways to split them into three groups.  Line them up and place two dividers either at the end of the row or in between the items.  You take a product of terms like this, one for each kind of item, and divide by $3!=6$ as the number of ways to order the groups.  The hard thing is handling the symmetries, like when two of the groups match.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring for now the restriction that the two groups must not have the same product, consider the number of ways to split
$$
[\underbrace{a_1, \ldots, a_1}_{b_1 \text{ copies of } a_1},
\underbrace{a_2, \ldots, a_2}_{b_2 \text{ copies of } a_2}, \ldots,
\underbrace{a_k, \ldots, a_k}_{b_k \text{ copies of } a_k}]
$$
into two groups, where the order of the two groups doesn't matter.
Assume that $a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_k$, i.e. there are $k$ different symbols in the list.

If the order of the groups *did* matter, then
for each symbol $a_i$ we just have $b_i + 1$ options: $0$ copies on the left and $b_i$ on the right; $1$ copy on the left and $b_i - 1$ on the right, and so on, up to $b_i$ copies on the left and $0$ on the right.
So the number of ways is
$$
(b_1 + 1)(b_2 + 1)(b_3 + 1) \cdots (b_k + 1).
$$
To find the number of ways where order *doesn't* matter,
we can almost just divide by two, except *if all $b_i$ are even* then we will half-count the one symmetric case where the two groups are identical. So the number of ways to split into two groups (the number we want!) is given by
$$
\frac{(b_1 + 1)(b_2 + 1)(b_3 + 1) \cdots (b_k + 1)
+ \begin{cases}1 &\text{if } b_i \text{ are all even}\\0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}}{2}. \\
=
\frac{(b_1 + 1)(b_2 + 1) \cdots (b_k + 1)}{2}
+ \frac{((-1)^{b_1} + 1)((-1)^{b_2} + 1) \cdots ((-1)^{b_k} + 1)}{2^k}
$$
Note that this includes the possibility that one of the two groups is empty! To remove this possibility, just subtract $1$ from the final answer.